# In Cheat Engine is it possible to give a preset (item active) inside cheat table?

Tags: cheat-engine

Suppose I have a cheat table for Cheat Engine and I'd like certain items to get activated/enabled when loading it. How would I go about that?

I noticed that inside the `<CheatEntry>` elements of the table, *if* I ticked the respective checkbox, saving the cheat table will set `<LastState Activated="1"/>`. Alas, this appears to have no effect next time the cheat table gets loaded.

Is there a way to automate ticking certain checkboxes, given a pre-existing cheat table?